# Install Windows 10 after Ubuntu 19.10 on a secondary HDD

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

This is my primary SSD which has Ubuntu 19.10 installed.

[SSD_Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1MOL.jpg)

This is my secondary HDD which has 500 GB allocated to Kali(`/dev/sda2`) and two ext4 partitions `/dev/sda4` and `/dev/sda5`

[HDD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfXOV.jpg)

I'd like to install Windows 10 on that `/dev/sda5` partition. Here are the steps that I took and the problems I faced.

1. I formatted the partition to `ntfs`, plugged in my Windows 10 Live USB, restarted the machine, started the installer, selected the partition in the menu, formatted it. Windows split that partition into four partitions: with three reserved for the system(about 550 MB in total) and 1178 GB as Primary. I selected that and hit next. Got an error message saying `Windows couldn't create a partition ...`.
2. I delete all the four to get an unallocated partition, it splits it up again into four parts as before, I hit next and now I get an error in the next screen while installing `Windows detected that the EFI system partition was formatted as NTFS. Format it as fat32 and try to install again`.
3. I restart my machine, go back to Ubuntu, reformat that `ntfs` drive to `fat32` and start the installer process again and I get the above two error messages again.

I've never installed Windows after Ubuntu, always installed it before any Linux distribution in a dual boot scenario. Any help/suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you not shut off the other (Solid State Drive(s)), and the other hard disk(s) then install Windows from a fresh clean hard disk (sda5)?

Comment: @vssher I have 1 ssd and 1 hdd. sda5 is in a partition in the hdd where I'd like to install windows 10. Can you please elaborate on what do you mean by shutting off the drives?

Comment: In BIOS is there not an area where you can shut off the Linux SSD? Maybe there are too many partitions on the HDD (?), I have always installed Windows first myself, it is just guess work to me also, I am not sitting in front of the machine, sorry.

Comment: If sda4 and sda5 are blank, could you not combine them and then shrink Windows partition to recreate sda5 later? And could you not remove the linux __swap disk__ also, for now?

Comment: Try deleting even that EFI partition

Comment: Yeah, had to remove Kali entirely to install Windows. :(